# Python: Case Sensitive Counter

Tags: python

I'm making a small script that needs to take any string as an argument and determine if there are any duplicates (letters or numbers). However, it needs to treat uppercase and lowercase as different entities. What I got so far is:

```
import collections
string = str(input('Enter Sequence: '))
x = list(string)

a = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(x).items() if count > 1]

if len(a) == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This yields correct results only if there is no both upper and lower case instances of the same letter, so it wont work if I enter i.e. 'moOse'

If anyone can help on how to make different case letters count separately, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: "However, it needs to treat uppercase and lowercase as different entities"  -- it does, doesn't it?

Comment: You’re implying `Counter` purposely makes values case insensitive. That would be very odd.

Comment: Change to `print(Counter('moOse'))` and see!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unable to replicate your problem - `Counter` *is* case sensitive.

Demo:

```
import collections

for s in ["aa","aAbBcC"]:
    x = list(s)
    a = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(x).items() if count > 1]

    if len(a) == 0:
        print(x, "has no dupes")
    else:
        print(x, "has dupes:", a)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a'] has dupes: ['a']
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C'] has no dupes
```

---

No need to use/import `Counter` to test if you only have unique elements. Compare `len(set(data))` against `len(data)`:

```
def is_unique(d):
    return len(set(d)) == len(d)

for d in ["qwertzui4567QWERTZUI","AA"]:
    print(f"{d} :" ,'is Unique' if is_unique(d) else 'has Duplicates')
```

Output:

```
qwertzui4567QWERTZUI : is Unique
AA : has Duplicates
```